# show 2 decimal place of a double using JOptionPane in Java

Tags: java

[how to round off the BMI value to 2/3 decimal place?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vAeE.png)

Comment: Birth year 1987 != age 26

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormatter to format the number of decimal points to display.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
decimalFormat.format(bmi);
```